# Some authenticated users can't access secure content or use the restricted API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm in desperate need for help on this.

I'm the developer of a site ([rockalingua.com](https://rockalingua.com)) that offers subscriptions to a Learning Management system. We have developed the LMS creating several drupal modules.

It's working quite well so far but we are getting reports from some schools that some students (authenticated users) can't access some content (They get messages stating that they don't have permission to see that content)

This seems to be random, but when this happens the site acts as if they where not logged in. If the log-in again they can access the content usually (they report they sometimes have to restart the browser for that to happen)

The pages that have this problem use a REST API created by us for tracking the students progress.

Searching the logs I realized that some time after a class starts using the system a lot of warning and notice messages are dumped to the messages log reporting unauthenticated users trying to use the API from the same IPs and urls seconds or minutes before, authenticated users where accessing it without any problem.

I've examined all the code involved several times and can't find anything wrong with it, specially when it seems to happen randomly.

I know most schools have a proxy that use a cache. But don't know much about proxies or whether they could be affecting this issue.

If so, what could be do to avoid school proxies caching dynamic pages?

UPDATE:
I include the typical response headers we are sending on the typical affected requests, and some relevant code:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 4590
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 26 Jan 2018 08:53:52 GMT
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Varnish: 1592956310
```

And here you have the code for a typical AJAX request that I have seem to behave as described sometimes:

```
  // ...
  if($form_state['data']['is_student']) {
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Go back'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [$form_state['data']['activity_type']],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'activity_modal_form_submit_callback'
      ],
    ];
  } else {

  }
  return $form;
}

/* Ajax callback to update the activity item after closing its modal */
function activity_modal_form_submit_callback($form, &$form_state) {

  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
  global $user;

  $activities_retriever = new student_task_activities($user->uid, $form_state['data']['task_id']);
  $activity = $activities_retriever->lms_student_task_activity($form_state['data']['activity_id']);
  $activity_data = array(
    //'activity_name' => $activity['title'],
    'times' => $activities_retriever->lms_student_task_activity_repetitions_assigned($activity['activity_id']),
    'task_activity_entity_id' => $activity['activity_entity'],
    'type' => $activity['activity_type'],
    'title' => $activity['activity_title'],
    'status' => $activity['status'],
    'progress' => $activity['progress'],
    'is_correctness_supported' => $activity['is_game_supported'],
    'percent_right' => $activity['percent_right'],
    'is_student' => $form_state['data']['is_student'],
  );

  $item_updated = render_activity_item(
    $form_state['data']['activity_id'],
    $activity_data,
    $form_state['data']['task_id'],
    $form_state['data']['is_student'],
    $form_state['data']['due_date'], false);

  $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
  if($activity_data['type'] == 'video' || $activity['activity_type'] == 'song') {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#activity_' . $form_state['data']['activity_id'], $item_updated);
  }

  print ajax_render($commands);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

As it calls `student_task_activities` needs the uid on the constructor to retrieve the activity data and in the described situations it receives a 0, the `activity` array is empty and when trying to render the activity item a notice is dumped to the log warning about the missing information. There is where it says the uid is 0 and that's how I realized the user id was lost somewhere in the process.

Comment: Cache-Control or Expires headers perhaps, not nearly enough information for us to help you. We can't see you site or code, we don't know how the schools proxy works.

Comment: Maybe cookies expiration time is too low?

Comment: I added some more information as requested

Comment: 2pha: That's the point. I have vague notions about what that kind of proxy does, but have no idea an what effect they have exactly on our site behavior. I tend to think that, in the schools having the issue, the have something misconfigured, or perhaps have a too aggressive caching policy. 
Our clients are the teachers, who don't even know what a proxy is. So I wanted to know whether I'm pointed in the right direction or we could do something else, before trying to sort of blame the schools IT team.

Comment: @MilanG : The cookie expiration is drupals default as set on the settings.php, 2000000 seconds.